# Solve a system of equations in $\mathbb{F}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, systems-of-equations

Let's realize $K=\mathbb{F}_8$ as $\mathbb{Z}_2[A]/(A^3+A^2+1)$ and let $a$ be a class of an element in A. Solve in a field $K$ the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
(a+1)x+a^2y=a^2+a\\
(a^2+1)x+ay=a+1
\end{cases}
$$
I need to grasp the basic concepts of how to solve this because I don't really understand how to start the solution. Any help would be helpful!

Comment: Surely the usual Gaussian Elimination yields the solution?

Comment: The coefficients are non-linear. Will Gaussian Elimination work anyway? I'm not sure.

Comment: The coefficients are elements of the field $\mathbb{F}_8$. Saying they are non-linear makes no sense.

Comment: We have linear equations in $x$ and $y$. These are the variables. Multiply the second equation by $a$ and then subtract the first equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the second equation by $a$ and subtracting the first one gives
$$
0=(a(a^2+1)-(a+1))x=(a^3-1)x.
$$
Now since $a^3+a^2+1=0$ we have $a\neq 0$ and hence $a^3-1=a^2\neq 0$. Hence it follows that $x=0$ and $y=(a+1)/a$.

Comment: I think $a$ is meant to be $A+(A^3+A^2+1)$ so it is automatic that $a^3\not=1$.